# Matlab applying ALEXNET to VIDEO for FACE RECOGNITION

Tags: matlab, image-processing, deep-learning, video-processing, conv-neural-network

i have trained alexnet on my own dataset which is almost 12k images from different people. I tested it on images and I got some results but I wanna test it in video. How can I apply my trained classifier to some .mp4 video. Here is the code which I used for test it on images but I wanna apply it on Video

````
clear,clc,close all
load('Classifier3.mat');

newImage = imread(fullfile('test4.jpg'));
ds = augmentedImageDatastore(imageSize,...
    newImage,'ColorPreprocessing','gray2rgb');
imageFeatures = activations(net,ds,...
    featureLayer,'MiniBatchSize',128,'OutputAs','columns');

label = predict(classifier, imageFeatures,'ObservationsIn','columns');

T = sprintf('This image is belongs to %s class', label)

imshow(newImage), title(T); ```
````

Comment: A video is a stream of images; Extract its frames and then apply your code.

Comment: thank you for answer, so basically i am just extracting to video from frame 1 to end and rest of the code will be kinda same, again loading my classifier and applying it to each frame right ?

Comment: You are going to use the *same* classifier for the whole video, right?. So you won't be needing to load your classifier again and again. Just loading it once will be enough and the rest of the code will be kinda same yes.

Comment: this project will be about face recognition and verification, i trained alexnet on images so want to also ask that should i apply this classifier to the whole video or should i  detect faces with cascade and apply this classifier on detected faces? system should recognize each person. And save them, for example ;detecting Mark's face and saving it to excel as for example 'mark enter the bank at 3 pm' Do you have any advice for complete my project?

Comment: Detecting the faces first will be better IMO because otherwise your classifier will still be predicting when there's no face. Although you can put a condition on the score to check its validity but it will still be better if you do this on the relevant data (i.e faces) only

Comment: thank you so much for  your help and advices